# Function does not enter the loop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def ConsultaDownload():
    VF = False
    VR = False
    consultar = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ConsultaRetorno.PNG')
    pyautogui.click(consultar)
    sleep(0.5)
    while VF and VR == False:
        print(1)
        sleep(30)
        pyautogui.click(consultar)
        sleep(0.5)
        finalizado = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Processamento_Finalizado.PNG')
        fRegistro = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('')  # processado e sem registro
        if finalizado:
            VF = True

        elif fRegistro:
            VR = True


ConsultaDownload()
```

At some point in my code I solve for a print(1) to see how many times the loop is repeated and I realized that in fact it doesn't even want to enter the loop. I have no idea how to solve this can anyone help me?

Comment: VF is false. It won't enter the loop. Do you mean `while not VF and not VR:`?

Comment: FYI: `VF and VR == False` is parsed as `(VF) and (VR == False)`

Comment: Or for someone who doesn't understand the shortcut: `while (VF == True) and (VR == False):`

Comment: Or `while not (VF or VR)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you understanding of the `while` condition is not correct here. I assume you meant to loop as long as both VF and VR are false, but in you condition you only check that VR is false.
To make sure that both VF and VR are false you should do this:

```
while not VF and not VR:
```

`while VF and VR == False` means while VF is `truthy` and VR == False

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot, I didn't know about this interpretation of the loop while, it will help me from now on